# ERROR Class app\Auth not found - slim framework v3 middleware

Tags: php, authentication, slim

I am using slim framework and trying to implement [slim token authentication](https://github.com/dyorg/slim-token-authentication/) as middleware, now whenever i go to

> localhost/project/restrict

i get the message "Token Not Found" which seems to be working fine however when i try to pass the token in the authorization parameter as per the middleware [documentation](https://github.com/dyorg/slim-token-authentication/tree/master/example)

> locahost/project/restrict?authorization=usertokensecret

i always get the error Class 'app\Auth' not found and in my error trace the below,

> 0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/dyorg/slim-token-authentication/src/TokenAuthentication.php(66):
> {closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Middleware\TokenAuthentication))
>
> 1 [internal function]: Slim\Middleware\TokenAuthentication->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
>
> 2 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(43):
> call_user_func_array(Object(Slim\Middleware\TokenAuthentication),
> Array)
>
> 3 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
>
> 4 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(73):
> call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable),
> Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response),
> Object(Slim\App))
>
> 5 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122):
> Slim\App->Slim{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> 6 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> 7 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request),
> Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> 8 /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/index.php(81): Slim\App->run()
>
> 9 {main}

**here the code i am using**

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Middleware\TokenAuthentication;

$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
];

$app = new App($config);

$authenticator = function($request, TokenAuthentication $tokenAuth){

    $token = $tokenAuth->findToken($request);
    $auth = new \app\Auth();
    $auth->getUserByToken($token);

};

/**
 * Add token authentication middleware
 */
$app->add(new TokenAuthentication([
    'path' =>   '/restrict',
    'authenticator' => $authenticator
]));

/**
 * Public route example
 */
$app->get('/', function($request, $response){
    $output = ['msg' => 'It is a public area'];
    $response->withJson($output, 200, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
});


/**
 * Restrict route example
 * Our token is "usertokensecret"
 */
$app->get('/restrict', function($request, $response){
    $output = ['msg' => 'It\'s a restrict area. Token authentication works!'];
    $response->withJson($output, 200, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
});


$app->run();

?>
```

Comment: Does the class `\app\Auth` exist? Could we see that class and the `composer.json`.

Comment: @meun5 i installed the library through composer, am i suppose to move it into slim folder ?

Comment: Did you create `\app\Auth` or is it a library you installed with composer?

Comment: @meun5 installed the library with composer, did not create any class, am i suppose to create it ? if you look at the example folder in the library there is a class app/Auth but its for the example i don't think its being used or called anywhere, am i suppose to move this app folder to a different path ?

Comment: Can I get a picture of your directory structure so I can get a better idea of how everything is laid out?

Comment: @meun5 there you go https://ibb.co/eEtLD5

Comment: Are you running the example from the example folder? If so, you need composer install inside the example directory as well

Comment: @meun5 no i'm running index.php from the main folder where i have core and vendor folders as well

Comment: @meun5 i just did an install with composer for the library and did not change anything, am i suppose to move app/Auth.php to another location ? if so where to ? as its only available in the example folder now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `\app\Auth` cannot be found is because it doesn't exist in the current composer autoload path.

First move the `app` to the root folder, where `core` and the root `vendor` folders are.

Then add

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app"
    ]
}
```

to the root composer.json.

Last, run `composer dump-autoload -o` in the root folder.

After that, `\app\Auth` should be in the autoload path and everything should work as expected.

Comment: thanks, i already figured that i needed to add it to composer.json and move the app folder to the root but what i kept on getting the same error until you told me i needed to run the command composer dump-autoload -o